# Download excel table via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to download an excel file using a post request.. i was wondering if this could only be done using some sort of a hidden iframe or maybe using flash as i have read in some post however im not sure how to do this. This is the code i have so far..

employeeExcel.php

```
<?php
require_once ("../models/employeesModel.php");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reporteEmpleados.xls");


$employees = new Employee();
$emp = $employees->search_empleados();
?>

<html>

<body>

                <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Tipo Doc.</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <?php
                    foreach ($emp as $datos) {

                        $id = $datos["id_employee"];
                        $image = $datos["image"];
                        $name = $datos["employee_name"];
                        $surname = $datos["employee_surname"];
                        $dni = $datos["dni"];
                        $email = $datos["email"];
                        ?>

                        <tbody> 
                            <tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                <td> <?php echo $name; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $surname; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $dni; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $email; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </table>
                <button onclick="employeeExcel();
                        return false" name="export">Export</button></a>
```

Here is where i do the ajax post

```
          function employeeExcel() {
          var uri = "employees.php";
          $.ajax({
          url: uri,
          type: 'POST',
          data: datos,
          success: function() {
          window.location = uri;

          }

          });
       }
```

Comment: Why use Ajax at all? A direct call to the page should open the download dialogue box if employees.php sets the correct headers

Comment: The file is empty when i open it..

Comment: If the file is empty, then your problem probably lies in employees.php not generating anything

Comment: How can i have the data in the response but not in the file?

Comment: Does not compute: if you're simply linking to the employee.php to generate the excel file, then it should output that excel file irrespective of whether it's in response to the ajax call or direct to the browser

Answer (score 0):

**The file is not empty, but just in the wrong format.**

HTML marks for tables (`<tr><td>`...) are not recognized as Excel file syntax. You need to create a real Excel file to use extension `.xls` of the output file.

For example, **try to rename the file extension of the downloaded file with `.txt` instead of `.xls`** and open it. You will see the HTML table output, which is not Excel syntax.

Have a look on this excellent PHP library to generate Excel file  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/